# Wrong values after passing from another activity using intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, int, parcelable

I'm passing two `int`s from one activity to another as part of a variable of my own class.

The problem is that the values are supposed to be 0,0 but it shows some random numbers like 126435,4.

the structure of my class (item):

```
public class item implements Parcelable {
private int id;
private String title;
private String desc;
private double lat;
private double lon;
private String pub;
private int p;
private int n;
//private int cat;

public item(int id, String title, String desc, double lat, double lon, String pub, int p, int n) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.pub = pub;
    this.p = p;
    this.n = n;
    //this.cat=cat;
}
```

Putting the extra variable (item): (I'ts correct. I've checked it and it returns 0,0 as it is:

```
Intent.putExtra("thing",markers.get(i));
startActivity(Intent);
```

But as it passes and I use `SetText` to set it into a textView, it shows some random numbers, whom I have no idea where they came from:

```
positive.setText(item.getP()+"");
negative.setText(item.getN()+"");
```

Then Im getting the item from the intent Extra:

```
item = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("thing");
```

the Logcat:

```
08-12 00:08:53.181: D/dalvikvm(5093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 459K, 19% free 12879K/15751K, paused 13ms+6ms, total 58ms
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): setProgress = 0
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): setProgress = 0
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
08-12 00:08:53.661: D/ProgressBar(5093): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
08-12 00:08:53.821: W/SurfaceView(5093): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=true left=false top=false
08-12 00:08:54.672: D/dalvikvm(5093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1111K, 21% free 12489K/15751K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
08-12 00:08:55.493: I/Async-Example(5093): onPostExecute Called
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: In your Parcelable implementation, are you writing and reading your values in the same order?

Comment: You're right that was that. Sorry for the stupid question and ty.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not read and write in the same order in my Parcelable implementation.